# How to Implementing LOOKUP function from excel to vbnet?

Tags: excel, vb.net, lookup

i have an excel file where the function using lookup. and i want to implementing this function with same data from my excel file. and i already make a data list in vbnet using datagridviews.
and this is  the function from my excel file.

=LOOKUP(2,1/(X87:X102<=AA87)/(Y87:Y102>=AA87),Z87:Z102)

what should i do first?
i want to show the value from this function to my datagridview.

Comment: What is a data list?

Comment: the data list I mean is the value or data that will be encoded to lookup function

Comment: Is it a List(Of T)? An array?

Comment: i dont know but it might be yaa